# Different sized subnets

Tags: routing, subnet

I am not sure the wording to search for and therefore this question has probably been answered before and i just cant find it.

I am puttiing together a small WAN and im using /29 addresses for the PtP links and i have 1 site that requires a /28 so i am wondering can i put a /28 and /29 in the same range, for example can i do the follow

10.11.60.0/29
10.11.60.8/29
10.11.60.16/28
10.11.60.32/29
10.11.60.40/29

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.  This question and answer may help your understanding: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Comment: Like Ron said.  And, for reference, the term is VLSM (variable length subnet mask).

Comment: There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that describes subnetting based on the number of hosts where it explains that you can subnet a network into variable sized networks. It also describes the main problem you run into with that, and the best way to avoid the problem.

Comment: When i first started reading the linked pages it didn't make sense but after reading a few times i found a section that explains what i was looking for, thank you for that, problem i have now is that it has opened a can of worms and i have more questions which i will raise in another topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
10.11.60.0/29
10.11.60.8/29
10.11.60.16/28
10.11.60.32/29
10.11.60.40/29
```

Yes - as long as the subnet don't overlap, you can split the subnets any way you like.